# PhpStorm 2016.3.1 - run single page in the browser quickly

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Since recently I use PhpStorm 2016.3.1 for my php projects. XAMPP works in the background and is connected to the IDE. It's a great IDE but I'm searching for a solution to run a single file in the browser.

The index file of Laravel loads over the run command perfectly. But an individual file makes a problem.

Everytime I want to open the file the browser gets me an error back that the directory to the file is wrong or the classes not found.

How can I setup that for a better workflow?

Comment: Please provide some details -- what file you are trying to open that does not work correctly? What URL IDE is using for this? I have a feeling that you are trying to use "Open in Browser" for ordinary .php file (e.g. controller file)... With frameworks ... where all requests get routed trough single entry file index.php it does not work like that.

Comment: Okey, i think your're right. I think laravel is such a framework which behaves not like a standard php project.